# Can we able to inherit and change the noupdate="1" in odoo?

Tags: inheritance, odoo, odoo-8, odoo-9, odoo-10

Is it  possible to inherit  from one xml and to change its updatable. I tried to inherit "Check Action Rules" to change the "interval_number" from 4 to 1 hours. To make it run every single hour. I don't think it may work because of noupdate="1". Anyone have any idea about this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes you can change the noupdate file by the help of hook. In the manifest file next to data add `'post_init_hook': 'post_init_hook',`

create hooks.py file

```
def post_init_hook(cr, registry):
    env = api.Environment(cr, SUPERUSER_ID, {})
    orginalxml=env.ref('module.external id')
    orginalxml.write({'field_name_to_inherit':value,
    })
```

Comment: is it work in odoo 8? I tried it but nothing happened.

Comment: Hi @KbiR I tested with v10 it works fine, I don't know about v8