# Issue in send by email attachment in sale(odoo10)

Tags: odoo, odoo-10

When Click the send by email button in sale, the default **sale order attachment** is loaded.

In my custom module I am try to change the default report to **custom sale order report attachment**

the  `email_template_edi_sale` id is `noupdate="1"`

so i added `'post_init_hook': 'post_init_hook',` in *manifest file*

in `hooks.py` file i added a function for change `report_template`

```
def post_init_hook(cr, registry):
    env = api.Environment(cr, SUPERUSER_ID, {})
    sale_template = env.ref('sale.email_template_edi_sale')
    sale_template.write({'report_template':custom_sale_quotation})
```

But The **default sale order report attachment will not be changed**

is it possible to use this method for changing the **report template**?

reference:[Can we able to inherit and change the noupdate="1" in odoo?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41850027/can-we-able-to-inherit-and-change-the-noupdate-1-in-odoo/41850422#41850422)

Comment: Did you check, if your function is called? `'post_init_hook': 'post_init_hook'` i don't know this method

Comment: @ julivico : I added from .hooks import post_init_hook in __init__.py file but the function could not be called.I check in base it is used in some modules like partner_contract_gender,partner_contract_birthdate

Comment: Look at this link to see how to create a init script by install/update of module: [https://www.odoo.com/forum/help-1/question/how-can-i-execute-a-sql-statement-on-module-update-and-installation-6131](https://www.odoo.com/forum/help-1/question/how-can-i-execute-a-sql-statement-on-module-update-and-installation-6131)

Comment: @ julivico: Thanks, I will check that